# How would I go about breaking up this list

Tags: python, list

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
x = []
for i in range(3):
    res = requests.get(f'https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore/ranking?category_type=0&table=0&time_filter=0&date=1581438205530&page={i}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all('table')[1]
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))
    x.append(eval(df[0].to_json(orient='records')))
    print(x)
```

it returns this:

```
[[{'0': 1, '1': 'le me', '2': 2778, '3': 5400000000}, {'0': 2, '1': 'Scuzzy', 
   '2': 2778, '3': 5400000000}, {'0': 3, '1': 'Los', '2': 2778, '3': 
    5400000000}, {'0': 4, '1': 'Omid', '2': 2778, '3': 5400000000}, {'0': 5, 
    '1': 'iTrolledU', '2': 2778, '3': 5400000000},
```

I want to grab all the "0", "1", "2",and "3" into individual rows

Comment: Individual columns I meant

Comment: can you add output of `print(df)`

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
x.append(eval(df[0].to_json(orient='records')))
```

To

```
x.append(eval(df[0].to_json(orient='list')))
```